# A simple convex polyhedron has $2010$ edges. Determine the number of vertices and faces.

Tags: geometry

> Consider a simple convex polyhedron $\Delta$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ with $2010$ edges.
>
> 1. How many vertices are there in $\Delta$ ?
> 2. How many faces are there in $\Delta$ ?
>
> Hint: Try do 1) by hands and then use the Euler characteristic formula for 2).

I know the relation using Euler's is $V-E+F=2$ but I'm not really sure how apply it to find the vertices and edges.

Comment: The number of vertices and faces isn't uniquely determined.  For example, a 670-gonal prism has E=2010,V=1340,F=672,  and a 670-gonal bipyramid has E=2010,V=672,F=1340.

Answer (score 3):

A simple polytope in $\mathbb{R^3}$ has each vertex with 3 edges by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polytope).

Each edge joins 2 vertices. Thus we can represent the relationship between vertices and edges by the equation:
$2e = 3v$.

Since we are given $2010$ edges then there are $1340$ vertices.

We can then plug this information into Euler's characteristic formula  to get the number of faces

$F = 2 + E - V$

$F = 2 + 2010 - 1340 = 672$ faces

Comment: It looks like you're assuming the polyhedron is trivalent?  Not sure why (I don't see that stated or implied in the question), but, if so, then, counting half-edges in two different ways, we get 2e=3v (not 3e=2v).  Also 2+2010-1340 is 672, not 673.

Comment: Good catch. I'm not sure what I was thinking nearly 5 years ago about assuming the polyhedron being trivalent.

Also, yes you found a transcription error (3e = 2v was incorrect, the correct formula 2e = 3v). And an arithmetic error (subtraction was off by 1).

I updated my answer to mention the assumption. I guess this problem is not uniquely solvable and this guy probably got his homework question wrong 5 years ago.

Comment: @DonHatch - "Simple" means trivalent! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polytope

Comment: @mr_e_man, thanks, I updated my answer with a link to that definition. I also corrected the slight errors mentioned above.